# Using jquery to access Mongoose schema key (Boolean) which is set to an attr, but it returns undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using node/express and upon rendering the .pug file below I send it a collection of Mongoose objects under the variable 'tasks'.  In the anchor tag with class 'task-link', I am able to set the id attribute to the mongoose _id, and I am also trying to create an attribute called 'completed' and assign it the value of the 'Completed' key, which a Boolean object in my mongoose Schema.  However, when I access the 'completed' attribute with jquery, it shows up as undefined.  I'm not sure why this is, given that I can access the id just fine.    Any help would be appreciated.

```js
JQUERY:

$(function(){
  $('a.task-link').hover(function(){
    if($(this).attr('completed')){
      let id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).append("<a href='/profile/delete/"+ id + "'>  Remove<a>");
    }
    },
    function () {
      if($(this).attr('completed')){
        $(this).find("a").remove();
      }
    });
});

Pug:

extends layout

block content
  div#main
    h1=title
    div
      ul
        each task in tasks 
          li.task-item 
            a.task-link(id=task._id, completed=task.Completed, href='/profile/switch/'+task._id, method='get') #{task.Description}
        else 
          li You don't have any tasks!
      
      form#add(action='/profile/add', method='post')
        input#task-text(type='text', name='task_text')
        input#add-btn(type='submit', value='Add Task')
        br
      a#logout(href='/logout', method='get') Logout
```

Comment: completed is not a valid attribute for an anchor tag.  Perhaps try using a data-* attribute.  Something like data-completed=... Then you can access it via $(this).data('completed'). On that note, method is not a supported attribute here either.

Comment: Another issue is that you are checking a string as a boolean.  The attribute will return the string "true" or "false".  If you do if(variable), you are merely against null or undefined.  As long as it is defined, it will return true. e.g. var f = "false"; if(f) { //Returns true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  task.Completed was returning a Boolean object, however, I wasn't aware of the HTML5 rules regarding setting attributes to Boolean values:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes

To fix it I just converted the Boolean to a string in pug and set that as my attribute:

```
-var toggle = task.Completed ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the data-* attribute for non supported attributes.

Also when checking a string for boolean, you need to compare it to a value.
If you just check if(stringval), you are comparing against null or undefined. if defined it will return true.

```js
JQUERY:

$(function(){
  $('a.task-link').hover(function(){
    if($(this).data('completed') == true){
      let id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).append("<a href='/profile/delete/"+ id + "'>  Remove<a>");
    }
    },
    function () {
      if($(this).data('completed') == true){
        $(this).find("a").remove();
      }
    });
});

Pug:

extends layout

block content
  div#main
    h1=title
    div
      ul
        each task in tasks 
          li.task-item 
            a.task-link(id=task._id, data-completed=task.Completed, href='/profile/switch/'+task._id, data-method='get') #{task.Description}
        else 
          li You don't have any tasks!
      
      form#add(action='/profile/add', method='post')
        input#task-text(type='text', name='task_text')
        input#add-btn(type='submit', value='Add Task')
        br
      a#logout(href='/logout', method='get') Logout
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was trying to create custom attributes. I've been able to access them fine without adding data.  Is adding 'data-' as a prefix the recommended convention?

Comment: I just tried: console.log($(this).attr('completed')), and it's still printing 'undefined'.  As a test I set 'completed' in the pug file to 'task' (the whole mongoose object), and then when I logged 'completed' to the console a string representing the whole object was printed.  And the object included the Boolean that I want to access.  Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Using data-* is compliant with the html spec. It will still work because html is very forgiving but you should follow the spec. As for it still showing as undefined, look at the whole object output and verify your property is correct.